# Elasticsearch how to exclude score = 0 docs

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a query like this:

```
{ 
    "size": 4, 
    "query": { 
        "bool": { 
            "should": [{ 
                "terms": { "property": ["iPhone earbuds", "iPhone 6 case"] } 
            }, { 
                "constant_score": { 
                    "filter": { "match_all": {} }, 
                    "boost": 0 
                } 
            }], 
            "must_not": { 
                "ids": { 
                    "values": ["doc 1", "doc 2"], 
                    "boost": 0 
                } 
            }, 
            "minimum_should_match": 1 
        } 
    }, 
    "sort": [] 
}
```

Some of the empty objects are just an artifact of how I build the query JSON and they all have meaning in most cases, this is just the simplest example I found.

Why do docs get returned with score = 0 and how should I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
{ 
    "constant_score": { 
        "filter": { "match_all": {} },
        "boost": 0
    }
}
```

Match everything and for this part give it a score of 0; this also satisfies your `"minimum_should_match": 1` rule.

You could reduce your example further (and I'm still not sure what you want to achieve with this query):

```
PUT /test/test/1
{
  "foo": "iphone"
}
PUT /test/test/2
{
  "foo": "iphone earbuds"
}
PUT /test/test/3
{
  "foo": "iphone case"
}
PUT /test/test/4
{
  "foo": "bar"
}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": { 
        "bool": { 
            "should": [
                { 
                    "terms": { "foo": ["iphone"] } 
                }, { 
                    "constant_score": { 
                        "filter": { "match_all": {} },
                        "boost": 0 
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "minimum_should_match": 1 
        } 
    }
}

DELETE /test
```

Comment: Actually it is as you wrote, I just indented wrong (edited). The match all is so I can sort by a field but in this case there is no sort field. This is so I can control, in some cases, the ordering of docs that don't match any of the terms. So you are saying that `"minimum_should_match": 1` is causing the `match_all` to return the score 0 items?

Comment: The `match_all` will match any document and `"boost": 0` will make sure the score on that should element is 0. With `"minimum_should_match": 1` you make sure that at least one of your `should` must be satisfied and with `match_all` that's the case for any document on the endpoint you're calling this search on. If the score of 0 is confusing you, try a `"boost": 0.1`

Comment: Actually I am removing results with score = 0 now. I'm asking how to make the query **not**  return docs with score 0 so not return items that do not match the `terms` in `should`. I don't understand if it is the `match_all` or the `minimum_should_match` that is causing this. Do I remove the `constant_score` and the `minimum_should_match` altogether? Is the empty `sort` a problem? The logic that creates this query is complex so I'm trying to understand the reason for the 0 results.

Comment: Yes, remove the `constant_score` block (with the `match_all` and `"boost": 0`).